# Are MVC Partial Views the best approach to bringing in multiple models into one view

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In my MVC project I have a Dashboard which is designed to enable a user to see multiple metrics courtesy of partial views backed by a model and brought into the main dashboard via `@Html.Partial("_QuarterlyMetrics")` and `@Html.Partial("_TeamStats")`. In total, there are about 7 UI sections dependent on other models outside of the `@model DevProj.Dashboards.Models.DashboardModel`. The question is, are partial views the best approach to multiple model dependency in a single view or is there a better performing maintainable approach? I've seen where some people create a parent ViewModel that takes an IEnumerable of all models a single view is dependent on.

Comment: Please note that the model-view-controller tag is for questions about the pattern. There is a specific tag for the ASP.NET-MVC implementation.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a container model specifically for your view.  In which, you would store all necessary models.  Alternatively, while not recommended, you could store your models in session and then load them in at run time.

Define your container...

```
public class CustomViewModelContainer
{
    public XModel x { get; set; }
    public YModel y { get; set; }
}
```

Then...

```
var container = new CustomViewModelContainer()
{
    x = new XModel(),
    y = new YModel()
};
return View("CustomView", container);
```